# Map applications

Tags: java, android

I have no clue why the following piece of code is giving null pointer exception.Please help!
This is the MapActivity.class.

```
    package com.dutt.rishabh.locator;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.location.Address;

    import android.location.Geocoder;

    import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;

    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    EditText start, finish;
    Button bsearch, btype;
    String source, destiny,url;
    List<LatLng> lines=null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start);
        finish = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finish);
        bsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsearch);
        btype = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btype);
        start.setText(R.string.source);
        finish.setText(R.string.destiny);
        source = start.getText().toString();
        destiny = finish.getText().toString();
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> x=null;
        List<Address> y=null;
        try {
            x=geocoder.getFromLocationName(source,1);
            y=geocoder.getFromLocationName(destiny,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address origin,destination;
        origin=x.get(0);
        destination=y.get(0);
        url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                + origin.getLatitude() + "," + origin.getLongitude() +"&destination="
                + destination.getLatitude() + "," + destination.getLongitude() + "&sensor=false";
        changeMapType();
        JSONObject result = null;
        try {
            result = new JSONObject(fetchData());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray routes = null;
        try {
            routes = result.getJSONArray("routes");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            long distanceForSegment = routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance").getInt("value");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray steps = null;
        try {
            steps = routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs")
                    .getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        lines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        for(int i=0; i < steps.length(); i++) {
            String polyline = null;
            try {
                polyline = steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(LatLng p : decodePolyline(polyline)) {
                lines.add(p);
            }
        }


    }
    private List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
    public String fetchData(){
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpGet request;
        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("somename");

        request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream source = null;
        try {
            source = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String returnValue = buildStringIOutils(source);

        return returnValue;

    }

    private String buildStringIOutils(InputStream is) {
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void changeMapType() {
        btype.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mMap.getMapType() == mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
                    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                } else {
                    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng bangalore = new LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bangalore).title("Marker in Bangalore"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bangalore));
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Polyline polylineToAdd = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(lines).width(3).color(Color.RED));

    }

}
```

**The following is the logcat error.**

```
07-23 13:43:36.300 11999-11999/com.dutt.rishabh.locator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.dutt.rishabh.locator, PID: 11999
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dutt.rishabh.locator/com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.dutt.rishabh.locator.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:75)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no clue why it is giving a null pointer exception.Please help.Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because you use "destination=y.get(0);" even if y can be null! Same for x.get...

Comment: what is at line no 75 ?